# Using EL expressions in JSTL forEach loop

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I am looking to count the number of commas in a string, separate the values and print n values based on the "max" variable I have listed below:

```
<b:dataTableColumn label="Misc. Documents: " >
    <c:set var="data" value="#{item.miscDocs}"/>
    <c:set var="splitPart" value="${fn:split(data, ',')}"/>
    <c:set var="count" value="${fn:replace(data, '[^,]', '')}"/>
    <c:set var="max" value="${fn:length(count)}"/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "${max}">
        <a href="/homekey/${splitPart[i]}">${fn:replace(splitPart[i], '%20', ' ')}</a><br/>
        ${max}
        ${max -1}
    </c:forEach>
</b:dataTableColumn>
```

When the code is set this way, it will only print one value.

[loop executes once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcdh4.jpg)

However, if I set the "max" value equal to a number, lets say 9.

```
    <b:dataTableColumn label="Misc. Documents: " >
    <c:set var="data" value="#{item.miscDocs}"/>
    <c:set var="splitPart" value="${fn:split(data, ',')}"/>
    <c:set var="count" value="${fn:replace(data, '[^,]', '')}"/>
    <c:set var="max" value="9"/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "${max}">
        <a href="/homekey/${splitPart[i]}">${fn:replace(splitPart[i], '%20', ' ')}</a><br/>
        ${max}
        ${max -1}
    </c:forEach>
</b:dataTableColumn>
```

It will execute the loop 9 times without issue other than the line breaks:

[loop printing 9 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35abi.jpg)

I have printed the "max" value for the variable just to see if it is showing the correct number of files and it is correct. What extra step am I missing for the "end" attribute to pick up this number? I have searched through other answers here and haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`fn:replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) replaces all occurence of a String by another String. It doesn't work with regular expression. So `count` and `max` don't contain what you think.

A simpler and more robust way to do what you want is to iterate directly with the table in `splitPart` :

```
<c:set var="data" value="a,b,c,d"/>
<c:set var="splitPart" value="${fn:split(data, ',')}"/>
<c:forEach var="part" items="${splitPart}">
    ${part}<br />
</c:forEach>
```